# LEADwithmap: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, trigger

trigger for Every time a lead is created, an account will be created or updated on the basis of email. if lead’s email is in any existing account’s email then trigger will update the account name to lead’s  last name, if lead’s email doesn’t belong to any account then the new account should be created with name as lead lastname and email as a lead’s email.

```
public class LeadContactEmail {

    public static void beforeinsert(List<Lead>Get_All_Leads){

        // Map<string,string>GT_Lead_Email = new Map<string,string>();

        set<string>Set_Emails_Lds = new set<string>();
        for(Lead Gt_single_Lead : Get_All_Leads){
            if(Gt_single_Lead.email!=null){
                Set_Emails_Lds.add(Gt_single_Lead.Email);
            }
        }
        Map<string,Account>Got_all_Accounts = new Map<string,Account>();

        List<Account> Got_all_Accs = [select id,name,AccEmail__c from Account where AccEmail__c IN:Set_Emails_Lds];
        if(Got_all_Accs.size() > 0  ){
            for(Account Get_Acc :Got_all_Accs){
                if(!Got_all_Accounts.ContainsKey(Get_Acc.AccEmail__c)){
                     Got_all_Accounts.put(Get_Acc.AccEmail__c,Get_Acc);
                }

            }
        }
        List<Account> upsertlist = new List<Account>();
        for(Lead Ld_Li_all : Get_All_Leads){
           Account aclist = new Account();
            if(Got_all_Accounts.containsKey(Ld_Li_all.Email)){
                aclist = Got_all_Accounts.get(Ld_Li_all.Email);
                aclist.name = Ld_Li_all.LastName;
                upsertlist.add(aclist);
            }else {
                aclist.name = Ld_Li_all.LastName ;
                aclist.Email__c = Ld_Li_all.Email ;
                upsertlist.add(aclist);
            }

        }
        if(upsertlist.size()>0){
            upsert upsertlist;    
        }
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger Leadupdatecontact on Lead (before insert) {
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        LeadContactEmail.beforeinsert(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

it shows error:

> LEADwithmap: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Comment: Should you not be updating `AccEmail__c` field instead of `Email__c` field on `Account` object ? If the correct field is `Email__c` then you will have to filter it based on that same field when querying for `Accounts`

Comment: The code you've provided looks fine to me from a CPU time standpoint. It's good to keep in mind that this error tells you that class X was the thing that was running when you ran over the CPU limit, but that doesn't always mean that class X is the problem. You'll need to dig through the debug log to figure out what is taking so much time (another class, a process builder, etc...)